# How to make concurrency work with dataframes writing into hive tables?

Tags: multithreading, scala, apache-spark, dataframe, concurrency

I have multiple threads on Spark 1.6 writing into the same hive table (using parquet files), when they try to write at the same time it prompts an error during the renaming part of write files into HDFS. I'm searching a solution to bypass this known Spark issue.

```
class MyThread extends Runnable {
          def run {
          //some code
          myTable.write.format("parquet").mode("append")
                 .saveAsTable("hdfstable")
          //some code
          }
}
Executors.defaultThreadFactory().newThread(new MyThread).start()
```

I get this error :

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:156)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.doExecute(commands.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.insertInto(DataFrameWriter.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveAsTable(DataFrameWriter.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveAsTable(DataFrameWriter.scala:221)
    at fr.neolink.spark.streaming.StreamingNeo$.algo(StreamingNeo.scala:837)
    at fr.neolink.spark.streaming.StreamingNeo$$anonfun$main$3$$anonfun$apply$18$MyThread$1.run(StreamingNeo.scala:374)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

caused by :

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to rename 
FileStatus{path=hdfs://my_hdfs_master/user/hive/warehouse/MYDB.db/hdfstable/_temporary/0/task_201812281010_1770_m_000000/part-r-00000-9a70cbea-d105-4f50-ba1b-372f555906ce.gz.parquet; 
isDirectory=false; length=4608; replication=3; blocksize=134217728; modification_time=1545988247575; 
access_time=1545988247494; owner=owner; group=hive; permission=rw-r--r--; isSymlink=false} 
to hdfs://my_hdfs_master/user/hive/warehouse/MYDB.db/hdfstable/part-r-00000-9a70cbea-d105-4f50-ba1b-372f555906ce.gz.parquet
```

I found this issue on jira : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-18626

Is there a way to make the writing part thread safe ? to make the execution one by one, one after another ?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm afraid not. We have tried it on our production environment and sometimes it appears a dead lock from hive catalog. So I suggest that you make the execution one by one, or use multiple process(not thread) to do this.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**

Use `this.synchronized{}` like below

```
class MyThread extends Runnable{
      def run{
      //some code
         this.synchronized{
            myTable.write.format("parquet").mode("append")
                   .saveAsTable("hdfstable")
         }
      //some code
      }
}
Executors.defaultThreadFactory().newThread(new MyThread).start()
```